# ¿Cómo unir n archivos CSV desde fish con herramientas de Coreutils?

Tags: fish

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo muchos archivos CSV, todos en una sola carpeta con el formato `Año-(Número de Mes).csv` y por lo tanto ordenados cronológicamente. Tienen los mismos campos, lo que yo quiero hacer es unirlos en un solo archivo para analizarlo. ¿Cómo le puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla seria usar `head` y `tail` junto con `-q` para leer de multiples archivos, usar la primera linea del primer archivo para crear un archivo y escribir todos los otros CSVs a partir de la segunda linea, ie sin la cabecera.

```
cat Todos/*.csv | head -n 1 > Todo.csv
tail -q -n +2 Todos/*.csv >> Todo.csv
```